# How do I split a number of words on delimiter in sed or with awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

**Remark: soultion must be only with sed or awk**

I have the following line: ( example from file )

```
     jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

in the following example we see that:

Before "=" delimiter we have the words

```
  jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf
```

And after the "=" delimiter we have the words

```
,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

so now I want to split the words before delimiter and the words after delimiter by sed ( I write a sed syntax - but this sed command give me partial solution ,

**EXAMPLE:**

```
        echo "jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3" | sed "s .*\(=\) \1 "  | sed s'/=//g'
```

I get the following results

```
,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

as all know sed give me the words after delimiter

what I want to get is the words before delimiter and after

please advice what I need to my sed syntax in order to get the words before and after delimiter ,

solution should be like this

```
 words_before=jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf
 words_after=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **awk**, you can use the `-F` option to set the delimiter:

```
echo "jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3" | awk -F= '{print "words_before="$1"\nwords_after="$2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo <source> | sed "s/\(.*\)=/words_before=\1\nwords_after=/"
```

---

Test code:

```
echo "n34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3" \
  | sed "s/\(.*\)=/words_before=\1\nwords_after=/"
```

Output:

```
words_before=n34r 38&Y EYH #EYHDCmhf453gf
words_after=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

Comment: I think you miss the second --> "

Comment: from some reason I get it in one line --> words_before=n34r 38&Y EYH #EYHDCmhf453gfnwords_after=,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3

Comment: you could try ctrl+shift+u and typing in the hex code for a newline `a`

Answer (score 1):

Would this do what you want?

```
$ awk -F= '{printf "%s\n%s\n", $1, $2}' x
jn34r 38&Y EY$@H #EY$@HDCmhf453gf
,e73e3bnd2wbyzd fr fr4fn3r f 4df 3
```

This is easily modified to provide leading and/or trailing text (that could even be different for the part before and after the `=` delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  It really depends on what your goals are.  Does this work for you?

```
$ echo "asdf asdf asdf asdf  = geitgm gao dbageiobna eb" | sed "s/=/\n/"
asdf asdf asdf asdf  
 geitgm gao dbageiobna eb
```

This works with and without spaces:

```
$ echo "asdfa asdf asd fasd f=sfsafd asdf asd fasdf " | sed 's/=/\n/'
asdfa asdf asd fasd f
sfsafd asdf asd fasdf
```

Comment: Not good - not works when - echo "asdf asdf asdf asdf=geitgm gao dbageiobna eb" | sed "s/=/\n/"     , when no space between words to "="